# convert image to gif fails with error

Tags: command-line, convert, imagemagick, gif

I have 506 jpg images I want to make into a gif. but convert fails with the error:
convert-im6.q16: cache resources exhausted 2022-12-19-152850_210.jpg' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/4083`

is there something besides `convert -delay 20 -loop 0  *.jpg  my.gif`

I should use to convert still images into a gif?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running out of default memory limits

Edit your config , located here `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`

Change the default values:-

```
 <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="1GiB"/> 
 <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="256MiB"/>
```

I would also recommend using flag  `-resize (x)%` to reduce the size of final gif significantly.